# How to download url file?

Tags: html

I just use `a` tag to achieve this, but my chrome browser just show the image not download.

```
        <a
          href="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20221222/ourmid/pngtree-super-cute-cartoon-vector-bear-png-image_6504049.png"
          download="your-file-name.png"
        >
          Download File
        </a>
```

Why download is not working ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download: _"`download` only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes."_

Answer (score 1):

Since the file that you're trying to download is not from the same origin as your website, your browser restricts it.

Try putting the file in a folder on the website and try again.